# HTTP Host Header redirect traffic

Tags: http, apache, url-redirection

Recently, I've seen periodic floods of traffic to my web servers with various Host headers that do not belong to us. The traffic appears to come primarily from China and a decent number seem to think we're a BitTorrent tracker. They come from a wide variety of IPs and User Agents.

Example BitTorrent tracker request (anonymized):

```
GET /announce?info_hash=%B8%86%E1hJ%A7%1Dm%AAvL%0F%CF%F3%F7%03%95%A8%AB%AF&peer_id=%2D5F21100%2D%04%0DA%DE%3D%D9f%A4%0Aw%A7%2A&ip=112.84.xxx.xxx&port=13777&uploaded=1150728262&downloaded=1150728262&left=2292077&numwant=200&key=937&compact=1 HTTP/1.0
Host: open.tracker.thepiratebay.org
User-Agent: Bittorrent
Accept: */*
Connection: closed
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-For: 112.84.xxx.xxx
```

Example TypeKit image ping request:

```
GET /p.gif?s=1&k=yoe7ink&ht=sh&h=get.adobe.com&f=7180.7181.7182.7184&a=204670&_=1422582942577 HTTP/1.1
Host: p.typekit.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: zh-cn,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://get.adobe.com/cn/flashplayer/completion/aih/?exitcode=0&re=0&type=install
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-For: 27.189.xxx.xxx
```

Note that the web servers in question are behind a load balancer (Linode NodeBalancer), so the X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto headers are expected; they correspond to the original requests to the load balancer.

As far as I can tell, the web server is not acting as an open proxy. The response to these requests is simply a 302 redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 30 Jan 2015 01:56:00 GMT
...
Location: http://open.tracker.thepiratebay.org/guide
Status: 302
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 108
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html><body>You are being <a href="http://open.tracker.thepiratebay.org/guide">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

The switch to /guide is provided by the Rails application that normally runs on these servers. It normally redirects some types of 404 traffic to http://ourdomain.com/guide.

I have two questions about this:

1. Why are we receiving this traffic? What possibly can someone gain by using our servers to generate large numbers of HTTP redirects? It doesn't seem like they are pulling off an XSS attack on the unvalidated Host header.
2. What do I do about it? Can or should I reconfigure Apache to reject requests where the Host header doesn't match a domain we own? Is there a way to figure out who is sending this traffic our way? Should I get a new IP for the load balancer?

Comment: You definitely should not be sending a response code less than 400 on requests for an unknown/unexpected `Host:` header... because one potential consequence is to increase your server load if the browser, which already apparently thinks you are that host, tries to follow that redirect... which could easily bring them right back to you until the browser realizes it has followed too many redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing, are very similar to what I have read in a recent news article.

It is about a bug in the Great Firewall of China, where it has supposedly been upgraded, where it can blast random sites with requests that it should have blocked.

Read the article [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/01/26/great_firewall_of_china_ddos_bug/) if you are interested.

Comment: And to think I skimmed a summary of Craig's post the other day and didn't put two and two together. I'm pretty sure you're on the nose here. It's good to know that this is merely nuisance traffic and doesn't appear to be an actual attack. Peak traffic flow has been about 10Mbps, which is at least better than the 52Mbps he was seeing.